# Why go runtime.newstack allocation is much more cheaper than allocating same size variable on the heap?

Tags: go, memory-management, runtime

I'm trying to understand some internals of Go. But one thing I can't wrap my head around is how goroutines' stack increases.

I see go using `runtime.morestack` to allocate new stack and then copy it to newly created area.
Although, how it differs from heap allocation?

More precisely: why function `stack()` works almost ten times faster than function `heap()`?

```golang
func stack() {
    _ = stackit()
}

//go:noinline
func stackit() [8000]byte {
    return [8000]byte{}
}

func heap() {
    _ = heapit()
}

//go:noinline
func heapit() *[8000]byte {
    a := [8000]byte{}
    return &a
}
```

Benchmarks:

```sh
❯ go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkStackIt-12     11208864           103.9 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkHeapIt-12       1309708           919.5 ns/op      8192 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/Users/asnelzin/dev/experiment/lstack  3.981s
```

As you can see, there is no heap allocations in the first function, but g.stack should be enlarged to fit bytes array.

Comment: From the benchmark, it looks like the stack allocating function competes in 103.9 ns on average, and heap allocating — in 919.5 ns on average, which seems to contradict your statement.

Comment: @kostix, I’m sorry. That was a typo, updated question.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler did not optmize away `stack` by not calling `stackit` in it at all? Did you see the generated code (run `go build -gcflags=-S` and/or use `go tool objdump` on the generated executable module)?

Comment: Yep, pretty sure. I'm even compile version of go with `stackDebug = 1` and compile this snippet with it to see: `runtime: newstack sp=0xc000046778 stack=[0xc000046000, 0xc000046800]` stack was increased.

Comment: Well, if you will call `stack` N > 1 times on the same goroutine in a loop, the stack (of that goroutine) will grow exactly once—to accomodate for the 1st allocation, and then will be reused. With N big enough (it is, in your benchmark), that initial allocation will be completely dwarfed by the following no-alloc cases. May be that's what you're observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as @kostix said there is only one stack grow so benchmark is not the right tool to those measurments.
I tried to measure single call of `stack()` and `heap()` functions but still got unexpected results: 115ns vs 15us.

So I started from the top and find out what compiler is indeed optimizing my code and removing stack allocation completly. There is a call of `stackit()`, but no stack allocations.

I rewrote example and add a prints to find a moments of stack grow.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const size = 256

func main() {
    print("main\n")
    start := time.Now()
    stack()
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}

//go:noinline
func stack() {
    print("stack\n")
    x := [size]int64{}
    end(x)
}

//go:noinline
func heap() {
    print("heap\n")
    _ = heapit()
}

//go:noinline
func end(x [size]int64) {
    _ = x
}

//go:noinline
func heapit() *[size]int64 {
    return &[size]int64{}
}
```

Running this with go version compiled with `stackDebug = 1` gives this output:

```
<...>
main
runtime: newstack sp=0xc000070f10 stack=[0xc000070000, 0xc000071000]
    morebuf={pc:0x10a2dcc sp:0xc000070f20 lr:0x0}
    sched={pc:0x10a2f09 sp:0xc000070f18 lr:0x0 ctxt:0x0}
stackalloc 16384
stackcacherefill order=3
  allocated 0xc00010a000
copystack gp=0xc000000180 [0xc000070000 0xc000070f18 0xc000071000] -> [0xc00010a000 0xc00010df18 0xc00010e000]/16384
stackfree 0xc000070000 4096
stack grow done
stack
50.096µs
```

Now clearly stack is growing to 16384 bytes. Important part here is copying of the old to stack to the new memory area.

Heap version instead doesnt change the size of the stack:

```
main
heap
6.096µs
```

This numbers seems unfair, so I double checked what there is a heap allocation and run benchmark again:

Escape analysys results:

```sh
> go build -gcflags '-m -l' -o sstack ./main.go
./main.go:37:9: &[256]int64{} escapes to heap
<...>
```

Benchmark results:

```sh
> go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkStackIt-12     24075922            43.80 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkHeapIt-12       5042449           236.8 ns/op      2048 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/Users/asnelzin/dev/experiment/sstack  2.804s
```

So yes, there is an overhead of creating new stack and copying content of the old one to the newly created. But on the long run, this overhead will be dwarfed by overhead of heap allocations.